# Go error: "embedded type cannot be a pointer to interface"

Tags: pointers, go, struct, build, interface

The following code gives compile-time error:

```
type IFile interface {
    Read() (n int, err error)
    Write() (n int, err error)
}

type TestFile struct {
   *IFile
}
```

Error:

> ./test.go:18: embedded type cannot be a pointer to interface

Why can't I embed `*IFile`?

Comment: Because it is forbidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language spec does not allow it. Relevant section from the spec: [Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is an *anonymous* field, also called an *embedded* field or an embedding of the type in the struct. An embedded type must be specified as a type name `T` or as a **pointer to a non-interface** type name `*T`, and `T` itself may not be a pointer type. The unqualified type name acts as the field name.

A pointer to an interface type is very rarely useful, as an interface type may hold a pointer or a non-pointer value.

Having said that, if a concrete type that implements your `IFile` type is a pointer type, then a pointer value will be wrapped in an interface value of type `IFile`, so you still have to embed `IFile`, just the value that implements `IFile` will be a pointer value, e.g.

```
// Let's say *FileImpl implements IFile:
f := TestFile{IFile: &FileImpl{}}
```

**Edit:** Answer to your comment:

First, this is Go, not C++. In Go, interfaces are not pointers, but they are represented as a pair of `(type;value)`, where "value" may be pointer or non-pointer. More about this in blog post: [The Laws of Reflection: The representation of an interface](https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection#the-representation-of-an-interface).

Second, if `FileImpl` is a type, `f := TestFile{IFile : &FileIml}` is obviously a compile-time error, you need a value of `*FileImpl` and `&FileImpl` clearly isn't. You need for example a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) which is in the form of `&FileImpl{}`, so it should be as I posted above.

Comment: type IFile interface {
        Read() (n int, err error)
        Write() (n int, err error)
    }

    type FileImp {
        string file_name
         .....
    }

    type TestFile struct {
        IFile
    }


    f := TestFile{IFile : FileIml}

Does f contains  FileImp field's memory copy ?

Comment: @sotter The `f.IFile` field is an interface type, it contains the copy of `FileImpl`, so yes, `f` contains a copy of `FileImpl`. If you don't want that, use a poitner, e.g. `&FileImpl`, so only a copy of the pointer will be stored, but it will point to the same `FileImpl` value.

Comment: thanks , I understand that, however, ` f := TestFile{IFile : &FileIml}` can not build.  In c++， Interface is a Pointer, that's why i want to `type TestFile struct { *IFile}` in golang.